# Obsolete controller logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a bunch of controllers, which also provide different versions of the API.

e.g.

```
/api/v1/controllerA/method
/api/v2/controllerA/method
/api/v1/controllerB/method
```

Now, I want to mark `/v1/controllerA/method` as `obsolete`, by using the provided .NET attribute.

However, I also want to log every use of an obsolete controller. To clarify - those controller methods won't produce a compilation warning/error, because nobody is referencing them directly in the solution. They are invoked by a http clients, in runtime. So the warning is doing nothing for me.

I know how to do the logging, I am just not sure what is the best way of intercepting the call ot an `obsolete` controller method.

Comment: In which action method? Every controller method that I mark as obsolete? I'd rather have it centralized somehow.

Comment: Automatic logging based on adding an attribute to something is called "Aspect Oriented Programming".  My advice is do some googling on that, and find some frameworks you'd be willing to use.  It makes use of additinoal compile-time steps to "weave" your logging into the app based on the attribute you added.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm thinking I'll just inherit the `ObsoleteAttribute` class and make it log, when the method which it decorates executes ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the pattern of [Passive Attributes by Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/)

He's got a full example on how to do this

Here's a naive implementation of a class that can do this

```
public class ObsoleteLoggingFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public ObsoleteLoggingFilter(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public bool AllowMultiple { get { return true; } }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        //check the action for obsolete, if null check the controller
        var obsoleteAttribute = actionContext
            .ActionDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes<ObsoleteAttribute>()
            .SingleOrDefault() ?? actionContext
                .ControllerContext
                .ControllerDescriptor
                .GetCustomAttributes<ObsoleteAttribute>()
                .SingleOrDefault();

        if (obsoleteAttribute == null)
            return continuation();

        var controller = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        var user = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;

        return continuation().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            _logger.WarnFormat("{0} is calling obsolete controller {1}", user, controller);
            return t.Result;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No point in inheriting from `ObsoleteAttribute`, since that will not do anything for me, right? The .NET compiler won't recognize it and yield a warning, if someone was to reference the method directly.

Comment: I like what he lays out in the article to use Attributes as markers and then have a separate Filter implementation.  This is also DI friendly.